# Ajax-pagination triggers only once

Tags: cakephp

i implemented the pagination-components according to the official documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html

I also included ajax-support. Basically everthing works fine except one thing: If i switch from page 1 to page 2 the ajax-request will work, after that i switch from page 2 to 3 instead a ajax-request a normal Post-Request will be performed. So the ajax-thing works only once.

My controller looks like this (short form):

```
public $components = array('Paginator', 'RequestHandler');
public $helpers = array('Js', 'Categorie');
....

$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'limit' => '15'
);
```

No the more important thing is my view: (jquery are included in my layout...)

```
$this->Js->JqueryEngine->jQueryObject = 'jQuery';

$this->Paginator->options(array(
  'update' => '#paginate',
  'evalScripts' => true,
  'before' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeIn', array('buffer' => false)),
  'complete' => $this->Js->get('#busy-indicator')->effect('fadeOut', array('buffer' => false))
));
?>

<?php 
    echo $this->Html->image('indicator.gif', array(
    'id' => 'busy-indicator'
    ));     
?>

<div id="paginate">...display data...</div>

<?php
echo $this->Paginator->numbers();

echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));
echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled'));

echo $this->Paginator->counter();
?>
```

That's all... as mentioned before: Switch Page 1->2 will work, Switch Page 2-3 will do a normal POST-Request, Switch 3-4 will work and so one...

A bit strange, so any idea? Btw. i tried different jquery-versions without any effect (currently i am using 2.0.3...)

Thanks - Best regards
Teyhouse

Comment: Does your JS persist when updating the DOM or is part of the updated DOM and is therefor removed and reinserted? After the update, does the said element have any events associated? (check with i.e. `alert(element.onclick)`)

Perhaps you need to setup JQuery event delegation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response - i almost was going to implement the hole thing by my self but it turned out that i had missed to write to buffer at the end of my files... so if someone has the same problem: Check if you have this line at the bottom of your code: <?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you just needed to also have:

```
<?php echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); ?>
```

In your app/View/Layouts/ajax.ctp file.